# Pass Argument to a function call from callable interface

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to build a utility library which adds tasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor queue. I want to accept a list/array of objects, a callable function, and a list of function arguments to be passed in the callable function. Now I want to pass these list or arguments in the function call I am making from the callable interface, but Callable interface only has one function which does not take any arguments.

Can someone help me in redesigning the structure? I want clients of this library to call one single function with above-mentioned arguments and the library should handle everything.

My Current class looks like this:

```
public class ThreadPoolExecutorUtils {

    private ExecutorService executorService;

    /**
     * Initialize Executor service with given number of threads
     * @param threadCount : number of threads on the thread pool
     */
    public ThreadPoolExecutorUtils(int threadCount) {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    }

    /**
     * Add the task to the queue of current threadpool executor
     * @param callableFunc: Function to be called from every thread
     */
    public <T> void scheduleTask(Callable<T> callableFunc) {
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    callableFunc.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
     * request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is
     * interrupted, whichever happens first.
     * @param timeOutSeconds : The maximum time in seconds to wait
     */
    public void awaitCompletion(int timeOutSeconds) {
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(timeOutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

}
```

In this, the client has to make the object of ThreadPoolExecutorUtils and iterate over its list of task and pass individual callable function. I want to abstract that for client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered anything from `java.util.function` package. I think its more appropriate for your use case than `Callable`, something like `BiConsumer` or `BiFunction`.
Since `Callable` output is not used in your example code i dont see the need to use it.

Comment: I used BiFunction and passed a list of arguments since it only accepts 2 arguments, it worked for me